# Paypal REST API - Sending GET Headers in RedirectUrls()

Tags: php, api, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, http-status-code-400

I'm trying to send the price someone paid for an item in my App over to my redirect URL after the Paypal payment is complete.

```
//Redirect
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . '/paypal/pay.php?sucess=true&paid={$price}')
    ->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . '/paypal/pay.php?sucess=false');
```

The variable `&paid={$price}` should send over the price of the item to the URL but I'm getting a 400 error:

> exception 'PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException' with message 'Got Http response code 400 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.' in /home1/*/public_html/Clients/rust/paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:174 Stack trace: #0 /home1/*/public_html/Clients/rust/paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(74): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...') #1 /home1/*/public_html/Clients/rust/paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(102): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL) #2 /home1/*/public_html/Clients/rust/paypal/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php(579): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL) #3 /home1/*/public_html/Clients/rust/paypal/checkout.php(69): PayPal\Api\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext)) #4 {main}

Everything works correctly if I remove the variable from the redirect.
Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Someone needs to go learn some PHP basics … http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Answer (score -1):

Remove the curly braces and use double quotes ("):

```
//Redirect
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(SITE_URL . "/paypal/pay.php?success=true&paid=$price")
->setCancelUrl(SITE_URL . '/paypal/pay.php?success=false');
```

*success has two 'c's.

Comment: Still wrong … variable parsing doesn’t happen inside strings delimited with single quotes at all.

Comment: Yep, good point, I forgot to change them when I copied the original.